# Повторно выполняется код при возврате во Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Во Fragment(ClassA) есть компонент ChipGroup, в нём два Chip'a, один Checked=true, второй false.
На обработчик ChipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener, повешен небольшой код, инициализируется в методе onViewCreated. При переходе во Fragment2(ClassB) с addToBackStack("test"), а затем из Fragment2(ClassB) обратно, через метод getParentFragmentManager().popBackStack();.
После того, как первый переключить в False, а второй в True и перейти во второй фрагмент и обратно, код внутри Listener выполняется повторно. Хотя по логике, должна быть лишь переинициализация.
Почему так, и как с таким бороться?

```
public class ClassA extends Fragment {
    private View view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView = null;
    private ChipGroup chipGroup = null;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        this.view = view;

        init();
    }
    private void init() {
        chipGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.chip_group);
        chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {
            Log.w(TAG, "print!");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: так и должно работать. жизненный цикл фрагмента отличается от активити. когда вы поверх активити А открываете активити Б - все вьюшки продолжают жить. у фрагментов же - все вью уничтожаются и создаются заново. изучайте жизненный цикл фрагмента.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Но почему при возврате выполняется код внутри слушателя (только если сменить Checked с дефолтных значений)? Ведь он должен просто проинициализироваться по новой и заново повесить слушателя. Или при возврате, у Chip'ов восстанавливается состояние и тем самым выполняется код внутри Listener?

Comment: возможно проблема в утечке памяти. видно, что у вас RecyclerView и ChipGroup объявлены как поля класса. позже вы их присваиваете. а вы их зануляете в методе onDestroyView ? если нет - стоит. без этого у вас утечка памяти. возможно из-за нее не выполняется желаемое поведение.